Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8082
I'm testing my node application but I'm getting error while runnig with IIS. When i start do npm start it's working fine but when i start running with IIS then I'm getting error. I added application pool permissions (IUSER, IIS_USER, Nerwork Service and Everyone).
I'm getting error while runnig with IIS. When i start do npm start it's working fine but when i start running with IIS then I'm getting below error. I added application pool permissions (IUSER, IIS_USER, Nerwork Service and Everyone).
I ran  net stop winnat, net start winnat and did restart of host network service but no luck.
Run on command:
C:\sites\test>npm start

node-open-ai@1.0.0 start
node index.js

Server started on port 8082
Run on IIS:
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8082
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1881:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1946:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:2044:7)
at Function.listen (C:\sites\dev-node-open-ai\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at Object. (C:\sites\dev-node-open-ai\index.js:60:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)

You probably didn’t ask search engines for tutorials yet, but you might try from scratch with https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

The error EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8082 indicates that your Node.js application does not have permission to bind to port 8082 when running under IIS. You need to make sure that port 8082 is not in use by another application and your firewall does not block the port.

Use netsh to grant the required permissions on the port:
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8082/ user=Everyone.
This command grants the Everyone group permission to use port 8082. You can replace Everyone with a more restrictive user or group as needed.
